# Camera doesn't capture media stream in WebRTC Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm developing a native WebRTC android application, in my previous project I did just fine with these options, but now I'm unable to receive media stream when I publish my media, here is my code:

```java
void startLocalVideoCapturing() {
        localVideoCapturer = WebRtcCapturer.createCapturer(this);
        Log.e(tag, "Local video capturer: " + localVideoCapturer);
        if (localVideoCapturer != null) {
            SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("captured thread", EglBase.create().getEglBaseContext());
            assert localStream != null;
            localVideoSource = localStream.getVideoSource();
            localVideoCapturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, this, localVideoSource.getCapturerObserver());
            localVideoCapturer.startCapture(1280, 720, 30);
            localVideoTrack = localStream.getVideoTrack();
            localVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
            localSurfaceRenderer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            localSurfaceRenderer.setMirror(true);
            localSurfaceRenderer.setEnableHardwareScaler(true);
            localVideoTrack.addSink(localSurfaceRenderer);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for getting `VideoCapturer`:

```java
 public static VideoCapturer createCapturer(Context context) {
        CameraEnumerator enumerator;
        if (Camera2Enumerator.isSupported(context)) {
            enumerator = new Camera2Enumerator(context);
        } else {
            enumerator = new Camera1Enumerator(false);
        }

        String[] deviceNames = enumerator.getDeviceNames();
        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            List<CameraEnumerationAndroid.CaptureFormat> formatList = enumerator.getSupportedFormats(deviceName);
            CameraEnumerationAndroid.CaptureFormat selectedFormat = formatList.get(formatList.size() - 1); // Default to lowest
            for (CameraEnumerationAndroid.CaptureFormat format : enumerator.getSupportedFormats(deviceName)) {
                selectedFormat = format;
                break;
            }

            if (enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
                CameraVideoCapturer capturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);
                if (capturer != null) {
                    WebRtcCapturer fancyWebRTCCapturer = new WebRtcCapturer(capturer);
                    fancyWebRTCCapturer.setFormat(selectedFormat);
                    return capturer;
                }
            }
        }

        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            if (!enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {

                List<CameraEnumerationAndroid.CaptureFormat> formatList = enumerator.getSupportedFormats(deviceName);
                CameraEnumerationAndroid.CaptureFormat selectedFormat = formatList.get(formatList.size() - 1); // Default to lowest
                for (CameraEnumerationAndroid.CaptureFormat format : enumerator.getSupportedFormats(deviceName)) {
                    selectedFormat = format;
                    break;
                }

                CameraVideoCapturer capturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);
                if (capturer != null) {
                    WebRtcCapturer fancyWebRTCCapturer = new WebRtcCapturer(capturer);
                    fancyWebRTCCapturer.setFormat(selectedFormat);
                    return capturer;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the partial log:

```java
I/chatty: uid=10163(com.namvdo.ion_sdk_android) captured thread identical 42 lines
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/chatty: uid=10163(com.namvdo.ion_sdk_android) captured thread identical 1 line
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/chatty: uid=10163(com.namvdo.ion_sdk_android) captured thread identical 1 line
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/chatty: uid=10163(com.namvdo.ion_sdk_android) captured thread identical 6 lines
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/chatty: uid=10163(com.namvdo.ion_sdk_android) captured thread identical 11 lines
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/chatty: uid=10163(com.namvdo.ion_sdk_android) captured thread identical 24 lines
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/chatty: uid=10163(com.namvdo.ion_sdk_android) captured thread identical 19 lines
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: local_viewDropping frame - Not initialized or already released.
```

Here is everything I got when trying to capture media:
[image]

Thanks for any help.